# Most efficient way of printing different types (from the same array?)

Tags: c++, arduino

I have a small sketch that reads a wide variety of sensors, which all come down to either an integer or boolean value.

Every loop I want to print them as following:

> "variableName; variableValue"
>   (which would give for example "distanceSenso; 432")

Currently this looks like

```
 int flame, distance, <etc>
 bool flame, touch;
    void loop(){
      noise = analogRead(SOUND_SENSOR);
      distance = analogRead(DISTANCE_SENSOR);
      ..etc..       
          Serial.print("flame;");
          Serial.println(flame);
          Serial.print("distance;");
          Serial.println(dist);
          Serial.print("motion;");
          Serial.println(motion);
          Serial.print("touch;");
          Serial.println(touch);
          Serial.print("noise;");
          Serial.println(noise);
          <etc for many more sensors>
    }
```

This works fine but isn't efficient. I would like to add each variable to an array and simply update the value each loop. This would allow be to use a simple for loop that prints each array element in a `Serial.println`.

However, this isn't possible as I'm using both int and bool variables. I could make two separate arrays or forget about the for loop and keep my current approach, but I'm learning to code and would like to know what the most efficient way would be to do this.

So, my question: how could I print each variable in said syntax in the most efficient possible way?

Comment: `isn't efficient`. This is the most efficient method, you can only get slower.

Comment: Does the order of the output matter? Is it okay to output `0` for false and `1` for true for bool sensors?

Comment: "This isn't possible as I'm using both `int` and `bool` variables." -- `bool` is an integer type that can be stored in an integer array. What is the problem; do you need to store the value as a `bool`? Do you need to print the value as `"true"` or `"false"` for `bool` values? More detail needed, and the question needs narrowing with "most efficient possible way". Most efficient in what way? Speed of execution? Lines of code? Memory usage?

Comment: What isn't efficient? Even a slowpoke AVR executes thousands of times faster than the RS-232. The real bottleneck here is the blocking Ardunio API. If it's too slow for your purposes, then maybe pick a MCU from this millennium, maybe even one with DMA, then write the code yourself.

Answer (score 3):

Sequential constructs in code are often the most efficient in terms of speed.  If you are looking for improvements in readability (eg, how many lines of code) then looping will help, but likely reduce efficiency in other ways.  That said, to reduce number of lines, say in a loop...

Use a combination of `enum`, `const char` array and `struct`.   (struct is optional here, but something I often use for readability when working with a large number of members)

I do not have your environment, but for illustration using ANSI C, the following shows how enumerated values can tie string descriptions together with measurement values into the same struct instance, allowing results to be  reported in a loop:

```
enum {
    FLAME_SENSOR,    // enumerated from 0 to max_sensor
    DISTANCE_SENSOR,
    MOTION_SENSOR,
    TOUCH_SENSOR,
    SOUND_SENSOR,
    // add more sensors???
    MAX_SENSOR
};

typedef struct { // optional struct
    int val;
    char descr[20];
}PARAM;

const char str[MAX_SENSOR][20] = {"flame","distance","motion","touch","noise"};

//simulation prototype    
int analogRead(int type); 

int main(void)
{
    int i;
    PARAM p;
    char buf[20];
    int result = 0;

    for(i=0;i<MAX_SENSOR;i++)
    {
        p.val = analogRead(i);// for use with struct
        result = analogRead(i);//for use without struct
        if(p.val /*(or result)*/ == some error)
        {
            //handle error
        }
        strcpy(p.descr, str[i]);//for use without struct
        sprintf(buf, "%s: %d\n", p.descr, p.val);//for use with struct
        sprintf(buf, "%s: %d\n", str[i], result);//for use without struct
        printf(buf);
        sleep(10);  //10ms delay, For simulation only, to allow clock tick for rand() function 
    }           
    return 0;
}

//simple simulation of  analog read function
int analogRead(int type)
{
    int meas = 0;
    srand(clock());
    switch(type)  {
        case FLAME_SENSOR:
            // meas = read flame sensor instrument
            meas = rand()%10;
            break;
        case DISTANCE_SENSOR:
            // meas = read dist sensor instrument
            meas = rand()%10;
            break;
        case MOTION_SENSOR:
            // meas = read motion sensor instrument
            meas = rand()%10;
            break;
        case TOUCH_SENSOR:
            // meas = read touch sensor instrument
            meas = rand()%10;
            break;
        case SOUND_SENSOR:
            // meas = read sound sensor instrument
            meas = rand()%10;
            break;
        // add more case statements ???
        default:
            meas = some error
            break;
    }
    return meas;
}
```

Comment: why `strcpy(p.descr, str[i]); printf("%s"... p.descr)` when you can just `sprintf("%s" str[i])` ?

Comment: @KamilCuk - Ummm.  I don't know.  Good catch :)  (i'll fix that)  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

From [arduino reference](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/analog-io/analogread/):

```
> analogRead()
>  
> Returns  
> int(0 to 1023)
```

So you are getting integers anyway.

Usually I create a temporary structure will all the different data and context I need to iterate through. Then a simple loop is sufficient.

```
struct data_s {
   const char *desc;
   int pin;
   enum data_type_s {
      DATA_INT,
      DATA_BOOL,
   } data_type;
} const datas[] = {
     { SOUND_SENSOR, "sound", DATA_INT },
     { DISTANCE_SENSOR, "distance", DATA_INT },
     { SOMEBOOLEAN_SENSOR, "someboolean", DATA_BOOL },
      ... and so on ...
};

for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(datas)/sizeof(*datas); ++i) {
     Serial.print(data[i].desc);
     Serial.print(";");
     const int readed_value = analogRead(data[i].pin);
     switch (data[i].type) {
     case DATA_BOOL:
          // custom int->bool conversion
          Serial.print(value ? "true" : "false");
          break;
     case DATA_INT:
          Serial.print(value);
          break;
     }
     Serial.print("\n");
}
```